# Clarifying derivation of Water-filling problem from Convex Optimization

Tags: convex-optimization

From Boyd & Vandenberghe's [Convex Optimization](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook/):

How did we obtained the highlighted part? I assume it is derived from inequalities above it, but $\lambda_i$ is not in the highlighted part.
[image]

<s>Also, here we have treated $x \succeq 0$ as one of the constraints. Isn't that implicit and not included?</s>, I guess x is not bounded to b e+ive!

Comment: You might find this useful: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33414/a-list-of-questions-on-boyd-vandenberghe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solve $$-1/(\alpha_i+x_i^*)-\lambda_i^*+\nu^*=0$$
for $\lambda_i^*$, yielding
$$\lambda_i^*=\nu^*-1/(\alpha_i+x_i^*).$$
Now substitute for $\lambda_i^*$ in $\lambda_i^* x_i^*$.